# OnEditorActionListener prevents EditText multi line

Tags: android

Without adding a listener into edittext, it automatically allows multi line in EditText, but since edittext is attached with any listener related to key handler (e.g KeyListener or OnEditorActionListener), those listener stops edittext from having multiple lines and could not to move to the next line no matter I entered enter,

Here is my code

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/editArticleContentForUpload"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:hint="Writing ! "

                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:singleLine="false" />
```

And it is my java code

OnEditorActionListener

```
editArticleContent.addTextChangedListener(new ArticleWatcher());
        editArticleContent.setImeActionLabel("Writing", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);//
        editArticleContent.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                Log.d("INFO", "KEY CODE : "+event.getKeyCode());
                Log.d("INFO", "ACTION ID : "+actionId);
                Log.d("INFO", "VIEW : "+v.getText().toString());
                v.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

as well as KeyListener

```
class WritingEditKeyListener implements KeyListener{
    @Override
    public int getInputType() {
        return InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getKeyCode() == event.KEYCODE_ENTER){
            Utilities.showToast(getApplicationContext(), "Hooray! ", 1000);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyOther(View view, Editable text, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void clearMetaKeyState(View view, Editable content, int states) {

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want is to be able to go to the next line when you click enter while you are trying to write inside the `editText`.

Kindly try this out

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
                android:maxLines="10" />
```

in this `edittext` I am able to press enter to go to the next line, although it does not include any scroll bars right now you can edit it as per your requirement in the layout